# How to optimize mysql query with an inner query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm always getting a timed out on the following query:

```
select * FROM `products` 
where 
    `active`=1 
and `group`=6 
and `id` not in (select `id` from `purcheased` where `userId`=14 and `price`>100 
and `reversed`=0)  
order by `price` asc limit 0,500
```

This takes 0.01s to execute, and in this particular case returns 0 results:

```
select `id` from `purcheased` where `userId`=14 and `price`>100 and `reversed`=0
```

This executes in .02s:

```
select * FROM `products` 
where 
    `active`=1 
and `group`= 6 
order by `price` asc limit 0,500
```

The full query

```
select * FROM `products` 
where 
    `active` = 1 
and `group` = 6 
and `id` not in (
                select `id` from `purcheased` 
                where 
                    `userId`=14 
                and `price` > 100 
                and `reversed`=0
                )
order by `price` asc limit 0,500
```

executes it 60 seconds!

I think this is happening because select `id` from `purcheased` ... is being executed for each row of the `products`.

I'm running the queries in mysql.

How do I tell mysql to execute the select `id` from `purcheased` once and than to re-use the result?

Comment: Typo in your table name: *purcheased* should be *purchased*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) is probably your best bet here:

```
select p.*
from `products` p
left outer join (
    select `id`
    from `purcheased`
    where `userId` = 14 
        and `price` > 100 
        and `reversed` = 0
) pu on p.id = pu.id
where p.`active` = 1 
    and p.`group` = 6 
    and pu.id is null
order by p.`price` 
limit 0, 500
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL misoptimizes IN and NOT IN with subqueries.  You can rewrite the query as a correlated subquery:

```
select *
FROM `products`
where `active`=1 and `group`=6 and 
      not exists (select `id`
                  from `purchased`
                  where `userId`=14 and `price`>100 and `reversed`=0 and
                         purchased.id = products.id
                 )  
 order by `price` asc
 limit 0,500
```

This will also work better if you have an index on purchased.id.  Actually, if this is the form of your table, then an index on purchased for (userid, reversed, id, price) should make this go much faster.